# MySQLi BETWEEN query to get data from text fileds in database

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I have a query :

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM table WHERE  CONCAT(Prod, Serial) BETWEEN '$start' AND '$end'";
```

Where Prod and Serial are stored in MySQLi database as a string. I need to update details of items between say AA1000 and AA1005. When I run this query it updates details of units between AA1000 and AA1005 and, "as a bonus", all between AA10000 and AA10050. 
Is there a way to get exact match for the text type fields using BETWEEN query?

Thanks!

P.S. I know that I need update query to update details. I'm using SELECT for testing purposes.

Comment: Do `$start` and `$end` always have the same alphabetic prefix, or could they be `AA1000` and `BB1005`?

Comment: Is the product part of `$start` and `$end` always exactly 2 characters?

Comment: can be differen.. there s whole bunch of them ..like bb dd da ma su etc.

Comment: but they are only two

Comment: So what do you want returned in a case like `BETWEEN AA1000 AND BB1005`?

Comment: I need to store Serial as a text to be able to add letter at the end of it in some very rear occasions ..

Comment: Which rows do you want to be selected when start and end don't have the same product code?

Comment: oh.. you mean start and end.. sorry... yes start and and will have the same prefixes at one given time...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This query should do it:

```
SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE Prod = LEFT('$start', 2)
AND CAST(Serial AS DECIMAL) BETWEEN SUBSTRING('$start', 3) AND SUBSTRING('$end', 3);
```

You could also split the start and end strings apart in PHP:

```
$prod = substr($start, 0, 2);
$start_code = substr($start, 2);
$end_code = substr($end, 2);

$sql = "SELECT *
FROM TABLE
WHERE Prod = '$prod'
AND CAST(Serial AS DECIMAL) BETWEEN $start_code AND $end_code";
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar but seting $start as AA1500 and $end as AA1503 returns 34 instead of 3 results...

Comment: What datatype is `Serial`? I assumed it was `INT`.

Comment: Following worked so far: CONVERT(SUBSTRING('$startunit', 3),UNSIGNED INTEGER)

Answer (score 1):

You are abusing the `BETWEEN` syntax in a very bad way. You're comparing strings, so

```
'AA1000' <= 'AA10000' <= 'AA1005'
```

is actually TRUE, because you're not comparing numbers, just strings. String comparisons go on a per-character basis, without consideration for length, so

```
'A' <= 'AZ' <= 'B'
```

is also true, even though a human would consider "AZ" to come AFTER 'B'.

Answer (score 0):

I have never personally encountered a situation where I have needed this, but I believe you can do this with Regular Expressions. [This may help you.](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/regexp.html)

Comment: While it's possible to express a range as a regexp, it would be very complex in the general case.

Answer (score 0):

Following worked so far:

```
 CONVERT(SUBSTRING('$startunit', 3),UNSIGNED INTEGER)
```

Thanks everyone!